# SharePoint 2016 Distributed Cache

Tags: caching, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, distributed

Is the distributed cache really necessary? I am not using any social features, no news feeds, no my sites, no blogs.

Just a single single server running Central Admin and one web app that host a two site collections. There are at max 200 users.

All the research I have done assumes a multi server farm with hundred or thousands of users. Is it really necessary for a single server install ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Its  important because it speed up page load. For example, distributed cache caches access tokens thus increasing performance in each user request.

Its by defaul On in the single farm scenario. It Will be easy to add new servers to the farm if you have ir configured.

Regards